# How to generate custom report based on table and column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

I have 3 tables, and in params I'm getting table names and column names.

Based on params I have to query on database table.

How to get the one to one associations records based on params (multiple tables and columns in params)?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want , you want to make a SQL string used by the params of table name and column name, am I right?

Comment: yes  you're correct Shawn, I want to make sql string

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the params you are getting, please? Do you know the assosiation names or you have to figure it out?

Comment: params be like {"tables"=>["table1", "table2"], "column_names"=>["has_one_columns_1", "belongs_to_columns1"]}
and association is belongs_to and has_one

Comment: Do you just use ruby to do this? I think it would be easy to do this, you can define a function, then passing the table names and column names to complete the SQL string.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I can't use just a ruby, it's rails app and need to deal with associations.